# Debug APK working fine, Release (signed) not

Tags: android, angular, android-studio, cordova, gradle

we have a major issue.
We have a angular app which is wrapped in cordova container.
We generate a debug and release APK version in Android-Studio.

When we deploy the debug APK version on a mobile the app is working fine.
When we deploy the release signed APK version on a mobile the app is working NOT fine. We are using in our app a own developed angular libary which is handling the http request.  We have a problem that our libary which doing the http connection not response.

Is there any configuration in cordova/android studio/gradle which could cause this issue on the release apk version, that maybe not allow this libary not do any http requests ?

Any help would highly appricated.

Comment: are you using [progruard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code)?

Comment: How can I check if we using progruard?

Comment: check out linked article, there is a `Enable shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization` section... (hint: `minifyEnabled true`)

Comment: We have in the build.gradle the following entries buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        useProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

Comment: so its disabled, don't have any other idea...

Comment: Please check `adb logcat` for errors when your app is "working NOT fine". WIthout an error message we can only guess what is going wrong and the chance to identify and fix the problem is very low.

Comment: @Robert Just curious, where is the "adb logcat" located? Is this log also be written on a release.apk on the mobile phone. The problem what we also had, that the release.apk we could not debug. This would be very help full. We added a lot alerts to locate the error.

Comment: `adb` is the basic tool used for communication with an Android phone when developing (part of Android SDK). `logcat` allows you to see the device log. https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat

Comment: Yeapp this is correct but we could not see as soon we installed the relase.apk on the mobile. Maybe we did some wrong we will retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we found the problem !
In our own lib we have been using a HTTP-Request with no timeout defined.
The URL we called in the Request, was not existing at this point of the project.
On the mobile in the Debug.apk  this did not matter but in der Release.apk on the mobile it matters and there was just no responses at all. We added to the http-Request a timeout and it worked.

We still not know why the timeout did not matter on the Debug.apk and but on the Release.apk

Also, there was a certificate error on the HTTPS-Certificate on the server which need to be reconfigured. Android is very strict on the the certificate setup which the debug.apk doesn't do. The complete certificate chain need to be provided by the provided certificate. If the certificate not provide all necessary information on the request than the release APK version will failure answered.

I hope it helps anyone.